# Jack Henry Digital Toolkit - Admin/Alerts() API - errorCode 40

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I belive I have a well-formed **Admin API Alerts()** *POST* hitting the proper endpoint; however, the response is always returning with a Network **403 - Forbidden Error** with the response payload set to error code 40:

```
{
    "errorCode": 40
}
```

My parameterized endpoint request looks as follows:
[https://banno.com/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{{institutionId}}/users/{{userId}}/alert/send/generic](https://banno.com/a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/%7B%7Bomb_institutionId%7D%7D/users/%7B%7Bomb_userId%7D%7D/alert/send/generic)

The *institutionId* is set to a constant provided by the client, and the *userId* is set to the **sub** claim provided the a customer OAuth PKCE authentication.

Additionally, my Authorization **Bearer** token is set to a valid access token generated using the **banno-client-creds-helper** tool and the Client Credentials OAuth flow. It looks good decoded as well(jwt.io).

I have looked the the API documentation, but I can find a list of error codes to get more details on **errorCode: 40**, and why my reqeust is failing with a **403**.

I am using Postman to POST to the Alert() endpoint:

[image: ()]

Comment: Does your [Associated User}(https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/overview/authentication/associateduser/) for the Admin API have the "Manage institution messages" permission?

Comment: Yes, our _Assocated User_ has the "**Manage institution messages**" permission enabled under _Profile -> Permissions -> Messages_

Comment: There are two concepts of Users, one are consumer users and the other are back office users. Profile -> Permissions -> Messages sounds like you might be referencing a consumer user (from People), in your back office if you click the "..." you should see Users & Groups, there is a User List, this is where your associated users/permissions come from for the Admin API.

Comment: An External Application was created with a "Service account" application type (not Standard) and then we uploaded a public PEM file and then selected the Signed JWT client type and the our Associated User which we created and added only the "Manage institirubion message" permissons.
Is this not correct?

Comment: That sounds correct, are you able to share more of your request attempt with the request headers and body?

Comment: I though it was correct, seems to all hook together.  Yes, I can.  I will do that with a new question as I think that is beyond what is allowed in a commented response.